# Polymer input capture enter event

Tags: polymer, paper-elements

I'm trying to detect when a user presses return/enter in a chat box to send the message. How do I detect this for a `paper-input` element?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

paper-input inherits from `core-input`, which fires a `change` event when the users hits enter/return or the element loses focus. If you don't care about the losing focus case (e.g only want the case where the user hits ENTER), you could check the `document.activeElement`:

```
document.querySelector('paper-input').addEventListener('change', function(e) {
  if (document.activeElement == this) {
    console.log('ENTER hit on aper-input');
  }
});
```

http://jsbin.com/godaqugacecu/1/edit

See http://www.polymer-project.org/docs/elements/core-elements.html#core-input.

Comment: It works, but just once. I have to click the field again for it to do anything (even though I can type in the field just fine). This seems like a super hacky way of doing this.

Comment: Can you clarify, "it only works once"? When I type in the paper-input, have it lose focus, and type in it again, I continue to get events.

Comment: I think it does not work if the input is nested in other polymer components. Everytime I press enter, I get as activeElement the parent element of input